# How to list connections in Secondary Nodes

Tags: mongodb, nosql, mongodb-atlas

In my cluster on Atlas, have a many connections in secondary nodes.
How to list this connections?

When execute this command, list the current connections in primary node.

```sql
db.currentOp(true).inprog.reduce(
  (accumulator, connection) => {
    ipaddress = connection.client ? connection.client.split(":")[0] : "unknown";
    accumulator[ipaddress] = (accumulator[ipaddress] || 0) + 1;
    accumulator["TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT"]++;
    return accumulator;
  },
  { TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT: 0 }
)


{
    "TOTAL_CONNECTION_COUNT" : 229,
}
```

But, I have 700 connection in replicaSet.[image: Connections in Atlas Server]

Thank's

Comment: My version is 3.6.14

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the command line tools

[image]

2. Copy `mongostat` command under **Set Up Diagnostics** section

[image]

3. Update **password** and add `--discover` option at the end
4. Run it in any command-line tool
5. You should be able to see the number of connections as below for all primary and secondaries
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

As mongo shell, this will print `client IP:port`, along with `connection ID`:

```
db.currentOp(true).inprog.forEach(function(d){if(d.client)print(d.client, d.connectionId)})
```

Note : Passing in `true` to `db.currentOp()` is equivalent to passing in a document of `{ "$all": true }`. The following operations are equivalent:

```
db.currentOp(true)
db.currentOp( { "$all": true } )
```

For further ref [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5085), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975531/check-the-current-number-of-connections-to-mongodb) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945107/is-there-anyway-to-discover-which-ip-addresses-are-connected-to-the-db)

Comment: This solution, list only connections in primary node,

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to the secondary node directly from mongo shell

`mongo secondary-node-address:port --ssl --authenticationDatabase admin --username uname --password xxx`

2. You should be directly connected to the secondary node, now run the `db.currentOP(true)`, it will list down all secondary node's processes.